# How to dereference optional field in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I need to dereference an optional field from an interface like below

```
interface Sample {
  key1?: Array<Obj1>
}

interface Obj1 {
  a?: Obj2;
}

interface Obj2 {
  b?: string;
}

const a: Sample["key1"][number]["a"]["b"] = "asd";
```

However it gives me an error at `Sample["key1"][number]` saying `Type 'Obj1[] | undefined' has no matching index signature for type 'number'.`

How to achieve this?

Comment: why not `const a: string = "asd"` or `const a = "asd"` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take out `null` and `undefined` at each step of indexing with `NonNullable`:

```
const a: NonNullable<NonNullable<Sample["key1"]>[number]["a"]>["b"] = "asd";
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=77&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpwLYAcA2KDeAUMsgNYQCeAjAPwBcyAglFHBQDwDyARgFZUA+QgF9ChUJFiIUPfsiIk49ZLIBMAbhFiJ0eEhV9V84sm7KAzmCigA5ptGEEAexCXkcBgDkXngK44cOG48dm8QPwCgkPRsPABtACJyagSAXQE4kF8MbmhUxLg0jITuNOQAXmQEuHMAEwT1IA)

Answer (score 0):

Sample["key1"] might Obj1[]or undefined. Try

```
Sample["key1"]?[number]
```

Comment: you forgot a dot => `Sample["key1"]?.[number]`

Comment: These are types. Types do not have optional chaining available to them.